# angular.js $apply bottleneck

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I am using realtime data to draw some lines using SVG on a webpage. To manage the data I am using Angular.js and to manage the visualization I use D3.js.

I set up a controller in angular that holds the data(lines). The data consists of some arrays of points (dictionary with x/y coordinates). Some lines are known at initialization, others are updated according to live data.

I set up an angular directive ('topView') which contains an SVG element. For each line at initialization, I add it as a path using:

```
var routeLeftLine = container.select("#routes").append("path");            
var routeLeftLineData = scope.val.route.left; // -> 1000+ points in there
routeLeftLine
            .attr("d", lineFunction(routeLeftLineData))
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("fill", "none");
```

For each line I want to keep updating (1), I set up an angular directive, for instance:

```
<surface-cable val="data.cable"></surface-cable>
```

where data is my data object on the controller and data.cable the array of points. 
The directive looks like this:

```
OCMSWeb.directive('surfaceCable', function ( /* dependencies */ ) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE', 
    scope: { 
        val: '='
    },
    templateNamespace: 'svg',
    replace: true,
    template: '<g/>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var cableLine = d3.select(element[0]).append("path");

        scope.$watch('val', function () {
            var cableLineData = simplify(scope.val, 1, false); // size grows in time

            cableLine
                .attr("d", lineFunction(cableLineData))
                .attr("stroke", "rgb(240,144,32)")
                .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                .attr("fill", "none");
        }, true);
    }
};
});
```

The structure works fine when I am updating the data using a timer, the change is reflected in the SVG.

The problem arises when I increase the number of points(>1000... I'll need even more in the future) that are in a line (both the non-changing, and the updated line have this effect) the performance degrades. The updating of the line becomes terribly slow, even when the elements to redraw do not contain many elements yet.

I can't find the cause. Does SVG/d3/angular render all elements in a svg again?
Is my way of binding data inefficient? Should I skip d3 all together?

I have tried to profile the javascript performance, and about 80-90% of the CPU time seems to go towards calls of angular $apply (which, I think, scans the DOM for changes?). Why does $apply take so long if an element (the line is a `<path>` element) has many data-points?

Comment: Can you show a fiddle or stmg ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @ethan-jewett did not fully answer my question, you did
 point me in the right direction though.

Because I linked the 'data' dictionary of my controller (containing both static and dynamic data) to the directive, I presume that angular does check all values in there for change. By moving my static data out of this 'data' dictionary, it does not get checked and makes this setup considerably faster.

Profiling still yields that angular gets slow when I increase the size of the dynamic data, and I assume this is for the same reason (angular needing to check all data for change). I am not sure on how I'll tackle this: I'll investigate whether D3.js has a more efficient mechanism for detecting changes in the data, or I'll split my long arrays in a static and a dynamic part (since they represent paths/cables, only the end of the cable can actually change. At some point a large part of the cable can be considered static.).

Comment: Do you have another way of knowing when your data changes? If so, maybe don't use angular's watch function at all since it is fairly inefficient to traverse the whole object when the deep watch parameter is true - instead have your directive expose an update function and call that whenever you know you need to trigger an update.

Comment: I have been searching for how to implement this, but all I find on updating a directive from a controller are the use of watches. Can you explain what you mean by having a directive expose and update function?

Comment: You pass in a variable on the scope of the directive (using '=' mapping) and then attach a function to it within the directive. This function can then be accessed from the containing scope. If that's not clear - probably best to look at using scope.$broadcast and scope.$on instead as it is more straightforward. I would link to the API docs, but it looks like they've temporarily borked the API docs website...

Comment: I get what you mean. In stead I created a flag variable which value is changed when the data updates. I use a shallow watch on this variable instead which dramatically speeds up the process.

Answer (score 1):

With this architecture, 1000 lines means 1000 directives, 1000 watches, and 1000 value comparisons every time you change anything on your scope, whether or not those values have actually changed. I doubt the root problem here is your d3 code, though reseting attributes for stroke, stroke-width, and fill unnecessarily certainly doesn't help.

Generally speaking, the better way to do this would be to have a single directive that takes an array of lines and handles the layout of all of your cable paths in the SVG. If your are looking at 10s of thousands of paths, then you might want to look at rendering them on canvas instead of SVG.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough on the situation: I have a few lines (3) that are static, but contain a great number of points (1000-100.000). Then I have 1 line that is dynamic (1-100.000 points) and needs updates. At the start of the program, the dynamic line is short (1 point), but already the redrawing becomes very slow whenever I use more than a 1000 points for my static lines.

Comment: If it's just this one directive on the page once, then I don't see why this is necessarily slow. I think you'll need to post a working example.